# In Ionic 4, how can I detect if I'm running in debug vs prod?

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

In Ionic 3, you could tell if it was installed on a device by using

```js
if (!(<any>window).cordova)
    isDebug = true;
```

This doesn't appear to work in Ionic 4. This always comes back as false.

What is the preferred method to detect if it's a debug vs a production build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**environments/environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: true
};
```

**environments/environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: false
};
```

**Your page**

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

@Component({...})
export MyPage {
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
     if(platform.is('cordova')) {
        console.log('cordova');
     }
     console.log(Prod? ', environment.production);
  }
}
```

**Commands**

```
ionic build --prod // Prod? true
ionic build // Prod? false
ionic s // Prod? false
ionic s --prod // Prod? true
```

Comment: How does `import { environment } from './environments/environment';` know which file to import?